# How to formulate multiple condition weighted average using sql in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, math

I want to calculate weighted average for h based on this conditions:

- If my table has only one row for p.id then use that value
- If there are multiple rows from join with same table2_id then calculate weighted average with thse condition

  - Use g as a weight if any of the rows in table1 has g value of not null or non-zero. Use n as a weight         only if g values for all rows are null or 0. Never mix g and n as a weight for one calculation.
- py-table is joined later based on other table that shouldn't matter in this calculation. Assume that table1.table2_id has many to one relation to table2.id

```
WITH py (table2_id, g, n, h) AS (SELECT
        table2_id,
        SUM(g) AS g,
        SUM(n) AS n,
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT table2.id) = 1 THEN MAX(d)
            ELSE 
                CASE 
                    WHEN SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(g, 0), NULLIF(n, 0))) IS NOT NULL THEN --avoid div by 0
                        SUM(d * COALESCE(NULLIF(g, 0), NULLIF(n, 0))) / SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(g, 0), NULLIF(n, 0)))
                    ELSE 
                        AVG(d)
                END
    FROM schema.table1
    INNER JOIN schema.table2
    ON table2_id = table2.id
    GROUP BY table2_id)
```

The problem is I'm not sure if the calculations mix g and n as a weight and not use only one of them in one calculation. If they do mix the weights how can i edit the code to prevent that?

I have not been able test the code with real data.